# How to add class name to a block in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm currently using prestashop 1.7.4.3, I need to edit the `header.tpl` file in the `_partials`. I barely know about this framework.

My problem is:

What I attempted: Tried to add a custom class name for the header logo

```html
<div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm-down hlogo" id="_desktop_logo">
            {if $page.page_name == 'index'}
              <h1>
                <a href="{$urls.base_url}">
                  <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$shop.logo}" alt="{$shop.name}">
                </a>
              </h1>
            {else}
                <a href="{$urls.base_url}">
                  <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$shop.logo}" alt="{$shop.name}">
                </a>
            {/if}
        </div>
```

As you can see I have added `hlogo` a custom class to the header logo and I tried `display:none` in my `custom.css`

My problem is: The newly added class name is not updated in the front office.

Guide me if I made anything wrong!

Comment: It will be updated after you clear the recent generated cache

Comment: pardon me for asking this how to manually clear the cache

Comment: Go to back office  Configure/Advanced Parameters/Performance/Clear Cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before, try clear your cache

To clear cache: Go to Back office `Configure/Advanced Parameters/Performance/Clear Cache`

You can find the clear cache button in the top right corner in the back office.

Also you can clear cache manually from `root_folder/var/cache/dev/smarty/cache`

If the problem persists to continue re-check the file you are editing make sure you are editing the correct theme's files

Comment: Thank you so much I was grinding my head to fix this issue clearing the cache fixed my issue thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

As Viira said, you need to clear your cache. You can do this within your admin panel by going to **Configure -> Advanced Parameters -> Performance** and press button Clear cache(right top corner) or you can delete it forcibly by clearing folders `root_folder/var/cache/dev/smarty/cache` and `root_folder/var/cache/dev/smarty/compile`.

And also it's better to turn off **Cache** and turn on **Template compilation** until you will not finish all your customizations. You can do this in **Configure -> Advanced Parameters -> Performance** as well.